# Accessing Webservice from file:/// with Edge fails

Tags: c#, typescript, fetch-api

I try to access a webservice that I've written in C#. I access it via Typescript and the fetch-api.
The access works flawlessly in Chrome and Firefox but in Edge it doesn't. I've tried it with POST and GET and both fail in Edge.

**The Typescript/js/html is run locally from disk!
So my Browser address field looks a little bit like this:**
*file:///C:/Users/.../WebServiceConsumer/view/index.html*

The Typescript method to access the webservice looks as follows

```
getData(url:string, token?:string): Promise<any>{

    let headers:Headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    if (token) {
        headers.set("Authorization", 'Bearer '+ token);
    }

    return fetch(url, {
        method: "GET", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: "cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
        cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: headers,
        redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
        referrer: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client
    })
    .then(response => response.json()
    .then(json => {return json}))
    .catch(error => console.log('error:', error));; // parses response to JSON
}
```

the method i am trying to access looks like this

```
public class SearchController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/v1/Search/Test")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("OK");
    }
}
```

I've set the CORS Policy in my C# code via

```
res.Headers.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

The Error i receive and log to the console looks like this
[image]

I have no idea how to fix this issue. What does the Edge do that Chrome isn't doing? How can I access my webservice from Edge?

**FYI**

1. The webservice is a C# standalone app with Owin
2. The access from "file:///..." is a must have of this project

Comment: Do you see anything in the [Edge console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/console)?

Comment: error: TypeError: Fehler bei "fetch"

Comment: In particular, check your pre-flight OPTIONS request as well as any subsequent request. I wonder if CORS fails in EDGE when you use a `file:///` URL. (i.e. look in the NETWORK tab of the tools, not just the console.)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `localhost` and `file:///` URLs are being classified in two different security zones. For example, if one is internet and the other is intranet, the cross-origin request will be blocked.

Another possibility with these security zones in Edge is that if your page is classified in a zone it gets a different security policy applied, which may be more or less restrictive.

If you have it tested locally in another browser, it might be simpler to do your cross-browser testing against a hosted test instance so it behaves like the real world.